# Transform a void function into char* C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, char, void

Some guy presented me with a beautiful code in my other question. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void encode(char* source, char const* alpha)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(source);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] >= 'a' && source[i] <= 'z')
        {
            j = source[i] - 'a';
            source[i] = alpha[j];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char source[1001];
    char alpha[27];
    cin.getline(source, 1001);
    cin.getline(alpha, 27);
    encode(source, alpha);
    cout << source;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to transform this `void` function into a `char*` one (it should become `char* encode(char* source, char const* alpha)`)? Apparently as it won't be a 'void' it should return a value but what value? Those pointers confuse me immensely.

Comment: You need to know what should be returned. `encode` is working with pointers, thus modifying variables in `main`. Maybe nothing needs to be returned.

Comment: Why should it be a `char*`? It works perfectly as a void.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char* encode(char* source, char const* alpha)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(source);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] >= 'a' && source[i] <= 'z')
        {
            j = source[i] - 'a';
            source[i] = alpha[j];
        }
    }
    return source;
}
int main()
{
    char source[1001];
    char alpha[27];
    cin.getline(source, 1001);
    cin.getline(alpha, 27);
    cout << encode(source, alpha);
    return 0;
}
```

Do something like that. And if you want to change a char array of main, your void function would work. :)

Comment: Thanks but should `int main(void)` stay? What do I need the `void` for?

Comment: @user3213110 See my edit. No, you don't need void. I just missed that. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
char* encode(char* source, char const* alpha)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(source);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] >= 'a' && source[i] <= 'z')
        {
            j = source[i] - 'a';
            source[i] = alpha[j];
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

Though it doesn't look like your doing anything with that return value.

(Were you supposed to return a copy of the `char` array, or is modifying in-place it okay?)

Comment: Is it really THAT simple? To be frank I tried the very same thing earlier today but it was in vain - didn't work out. Well.. My stupid assignment says I should do it so. I should only modify the array and print it out, that's about it.

Comment: Since a void function() just means there is no return statement, changing the function to char* function() means that a return statement with a type of char* is expected. Passing char* source as a argument to the function passes a pointer to the c style string of type char*. This means when you do anything to the 'source' char* array in your function it is pointing the the location of the 'source' array outside of the function and changing the values in it. The return of source is redundant since you should already have access to the modified array that was passed as a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `char *` really only makes sense if you're trying to alert the calling function an error has occurred:

```
char *encode(char *source, char const *alpha)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(source);

    /* Check For Argument Errors */
    if((source == NULL) || (alpha == NULL))
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] >= 'a' && source[i] <= 'z')
        {
            j = source[i] - 'a';
            source[i] = alpha[j];
        }
    }

    return source;
}
```

The calling function can check for errors like this:

```
if(encode(source, alpha) == NULL)
{
    printf("Encoding error!\n");
    return -1;
}
else
{
    cout << source;
}
```